# 2 particles collision - deriving the equation for an energy which can become mass of new particles!

Tags: homework-and-exercises, collision, pair-production

**Q1:**
Lets say a particle with mass $m_1$ and kinetic energy $W_k$ colides with a particle of mass $m_2$ at rest. Can anyone explain why do both particless ($m_1$ and $m_2$) plus an aditionall mass $m$ still exist after the colission?

[image]

**Q2:**
Are particless $m_1$ and $m_2$ stationary? Yes/no?

**Q3:**
Is the blob of new particles with mass $m$ moving as one with a momentum $\vec{p}$ which is same as momentum $\vec{p}$ before the colision? Yes/no?

**Q4:**
Is it possible to derive the available energy $W_{av}$ which can be transformed into mass $m$ of new particles? How do we do it? I know that it has to do something with momentum conservation, energy conservation and an invariant $W^2 = p^2c^2 + {W_0}^2$.

Comment: [Homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange)

Comment: This is not a homework question... It is only theoretical. If you like, you can anwser only questions **Q1**, **Q2** and **Q3** and i ll derive **Q4** myself later.

Comment: Q1. I don't see what you are confused about? Q2: In the question, you have stated that they have a momentum $\vec p$, and this looks like a special relativistic problem (due to the last  equation), so $\vec p = \gamma m\vec v$, if If $ \vec v  = 0$, then $\vec p = 0$, Q3. Conservation of Momentum. Q4. You've pretty much solved it in the question itself.

Comment: It doesnt make it homework, because i did try to find proton proton collision and got no good anwsers. All is too scientiffic. So this is why i asked here.

Comment: I already solved this myself with a help of different forum: http://www.physicsforums.com/ It is better. Why? Because they anwser a fairly simple question i gave. It was a yes/no question and here noone provided.

Comment: Let me say again: your default approach to solving problems in relativistic kinematics should *always* be to put everything into 4-vector form. That way (1) all the operations are linear (meaning no #@&+^! $\gamma$s) and (2) masses (being the dot product of a 4-vector with itself and therefor *Lorentz invariant*) can be found in *any* convenient frame of reference.

Comment: @71GA if you have tried something, you should also add it to your question so we can help you find where you made a mistake.

Comment: I solved this problem and now got stuck with a different - harder - one where 2 protons are moving with different kinetic energies. I ve posted it here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/71510/2-protons-collision-both-with-different-kinetic-energies-i-dont-know-what-t

Answer (score 0):

Q1: The collision releases energy, and energy = mass/c^2.

Q2: Each particle thinks that the other one is moving and that it is stationary. Defining "not moving" requires a "reference frame" in both relativity and plain old Newtonian physics.

Q3: The blob has the same momentum as m1 (assuming that the blob includes the original particles m1 and m2). The formula for momentum in relativity is a bit tricky (meaning that you have to know what you are doing or else you could make a mistake). Think of it this way: if m1 impacts a large plate (mass of plate >> m1+m1+energy/c^2) directly or m1 hits m2 and then the blob hits the plate, then the plate will be moving at the same speed either way (assuming that the plate absorbes everything).